# How to combine multiple sprite sheets from multiple sources (Actionscript/Starling)

Tags: sprites, spritesheet, text-based

In starling, it's faster if you use BitmapText instead of traditional text. Which is well great except for one issue. Right now the sprite sheet I was making was with a single Fla. I just created the sheet from Flash IDE.

The bitmap text however is generated using a tool like BMFont . Which generates it's own sprite sheet. Now, imagine I have three or four types of texts . Also for some reason I have multiple Sprite sheets of assets.

So the question is, how do I stick multiple sprite sheets together. Is there any available tool for it?

Does using multiple sprite cause performance issues?

Comment: Combining bitmap fonts with other sprite sheets seems like a very odd requirement. Are you sure you actually need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any existing tool for that purpose. What I would do is write a custom script (I'd use Python, but using some other scripting language would work just as well) that first invokes ImageMagick to combine the separate images, then reads in the accompanying XMLs to get data for each of the spritesheets, modifies the data as needed, and then writes the modified data into a new combined XML.

Answer (score 2):

To combine multiple sprite-sheets you'll have to revert to a method like jhocking describes in his post (eg. combine the images and make sure coordinates in the XML files are being updated accordingly).

That's a suboptimal way to go about it though. Instead of exporting several sprite sheets, why not export just one? [Texture-Packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) is a really great tool for this. You can simply create a folder, export all your sprites there (eg. animations as image-sequence) and drag the folder into texture-packer. The tool will combine all the images from that folder into a sprite-sheet and even auto-detect new images when you add them.

When it comes to special sprite-sheets such as fonts, you usually have to resort to other methods. In case of the starling framework, this is a non-issue though. You can pack your font-bitmap (the whole sheet) into a sprite-sheet like any other sprite. Then in starling you do something like this:

```
var font:BitmapFont = new BitmapFont(atlas.getTexture("fontName"), xmlData);
```

Where `atlas` is the loaded texture atlas. "fontName" references the font-sheet inside the atlas. The `xmlData` parameter is the loaded font data (file sometimes has `.fnt` extension).

Comment: Thanks Bummzack, texture packer would do. So can I pack my fonts and other sprites together? Basically right now I think my game would have atleast 5 variations of fonts (I want them to be bitmap fonts) . What would you recommend, pack them in one or have different atlas's for each?

Comment: @FahimAkhter You can pack the fonts and sprites into one sheet. Depending on the devices you're targeting I wouldn't use sheets greater than 2048x2048 or even 1024x1024.

Comment: X number of sheets. No sheet exceeding 1024x1024, got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand you right but it seems you are looking for something like http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker for creating a textureatlas

Comment: He's talking about stitching together multiple spritesheets, not generating a new spritesheet.

Answer (score 0):

This forum post also explains how it's done.
http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/bitmapfonts-sharing-a-textureatlas

Comment: You might want to make a summary of the method behind that link. Links can become invalid...

Comment: Also, link only answers are better suited as comment.